# Mongoose find results in empty array and pretty sure all models match up

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am sure this has been answered before but I could not get anything to work.

I have a simple Node.js application that just gets an id and looks up an incident by that id. For now I would like to just get back all incidents no matter their ID.

Below is my code, I have checked and the DB connection string is working correctly (I can see connections when starting my application)

Controller

```
// Model
const Incident = require('../models/incident');

exports.fetchByID = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    Incident.find({}, (err, incident) => {
        if(err) console.log(err)
        if(!incident || incident == []) return res.json({success: false, message: 'No incident found'});
        if(incident) return res.json({success: true, incident});
    });
};
```

Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const incidentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },

    createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Incident', incidentSchema);
```

How I am connecting

```
// Mongo Connection
const dbString = `${config.db}/incident`;
mongoose.connect(dbString, { autoReconnect: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, (err) => {
    if (!err) console.log('MongoDB has connected successfully.');
});
```

Name of DB.collection in Mongo Atlas `incident.incidents`

There is 1 document in the DB currently.

```
{
 "success": true,
 "incident": [] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is weird... I copied the connection string from another application that uses the same DB. The only difference was `?retryWrites=true` so I tried adding that to my connection string and it works. I have zero clue why that would matter when I am trying to read not do any writes.

Can anyone explain what happened and why it was saying it connected and everything but returned an empty array instead of the correct value?